# How to capture eclipse console output using the consolePatternMatchListeners?

Tags: java, eclipse, plugins, console

I'm writing an plugin that should capture the eclipse console output. my plugin.xml includes

```
<extension
     point="org.eclipse.ui.console.consolePatternMatchListeners">
  <consolePatternMatchListener
        class="eventhandling.PatternMatcher"
        id="eventhandling.PatternMatcher"
        regex=".*">
        <enablement>
        <test property="org.eclipse.ui.console.consoleTypeTest" value="exampleConsole"/>
     </enablement>
  </consolePatternMatchListener>
```

However my PatternMatcher, which is as following, is not called. I would like to know how to create working code that captures everything from an eclipse console.

```
import org.eclipse.ui.console.*;;
public class PatternMatcher implements IPatternMatchListener {

    @Override
    public void connect(TextConsole console) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        System.out.println("testing");

    }

    @Override
    public void disconnect() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        System.out.println("testing");

    }

    @Override
    public void matchFound(PatternMatchEvent event) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        System.out.println("testing");
    }

    @Override
    public String getPattern() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        System.out.println("testing");
        return "*";
    }

    @Override
    public int getCompilerFlags() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        System.out.println("testing");
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public String getLineQualifier() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        System.out.println("testing");
        return null;
    }

}
```

Comment: Well this is only enabled for consoles of type `exampleConsole`. Is that what your console type is?

Comment: @greg-449 I don't know what my console type is. If I leave it blank it also doesn't work. The problem is is there is almost no Documentation about the console type. I tried the console types defined in this [post](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=175888#c6) but it also doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't say what console type you want to match, but here is the actual Java Stack Trace console pattern matcher showing some of the more usual enablement values:

```xml
<consolePatternMatchListener
      class="org.eclipse.jdt.internal.debug.ui.console.JavaConsoleTracker"
      regex="\(\w*${java_extensions_regex}\S*\)"
      qualifier="${java_extensions_regex}"
      id="org.eclipse.jdt.debug.ui.JavaConsoleTracker">
   <enablement>
      <or>
        <test property="org.eclipse.ui.console.consoleTypeTest" value="javaStackTraceConsole"/>
        <test property="org.eclipse.debug.ui.processTypeTest" value="java"/>
        <test property="org.eclipse.debug.ui.processTypeTest" value="org.eclipse.ant.ui.antProcess"/>
      </or>
   </enablement>
</consolePatternMatchListener>
```

I believe this is matching the Java stack trace console, and the process output consoles for Java and Ant programs.

Comment: Thanks, this seems to work like I had imagined it. Thanks a lot!